# Transposition for baritone saxophone in EFlat

Tags: theory, modulation

Is this the correct transposition for a baritone saxophone in eflat pleast? What will the new key be?[image]

Comment: Take a look at a previous question - Modulation theory exercise for baritone sax (Eb).

Answer (score 1):

When a tranposing instrument pitched in E flat plays a written C, the actual note produced is E flat.  So, a minor third higher or a major sixth lower or an octave or more away from that.  Knowing that the baritone sax is pitched in E flat alone does not tell you which octave.  You need to know.  The alto sax is a major 6th lower and the baritone is an octave and a major 6th lower.  So, you need to compensate for this shift by writing an octave and a major 6th higher.

Your music is in F.  A major 6th higher is D so you should write the sax part in D.  Your first note is F and you have correctly moved it up an octave and a 6th.

Actually, the two are linked.  Since it opens on the tonic, figuring that the sax part opens with D tells you that the key is D.

Another way to get the key is to know that the sax will have 3 more sharps.  Think of flats as negative sharps.  Concert pitch is 1 flat so -1 sharp and the sax will have 2 sharps.